# Discord.py have a command run on one specific channel

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So, Basically what I am trying to do is I've been trying to make a bot that takes user input, then tells them if whatever they put in is available or not. I got the randomizer and Availability, and the command works well with the prefix, but when i run it, it's running on other channels as well. IE: I type something in one channel, it makes the message in another channel. What i want is for the user to be able to use the command in ONE channel. Also, the command is running without the prefix as well, is there any reason why? Am I doing something wrong, because I feel like I am. Here's my code for reference:

```py
import discord
from discord import Intents, channel, colour
from apscheduler.schedulers.asyncio import AsyncIOScheduler
from discord import Embed
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot as BotBase
from discord.ext.commands.core import check
from discord.ext.commands.errors import CommandNotFound
from discord.message import Message
from ygoprodeck import *
import random

from ..db import db

PREFIX = "+"
OWNER_IDS = [OWNER_ID]
ygo = YGOPro()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='#')

class Bot(BotBase):
    def __init__(self):
        self.PREFIX = PREFIX
        self.ready = False
        self.guild = None
        self.scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler()

        db.autosave(self.scheduler)
        super().__init__(
            command_prefix=PREFIX,
            owner_ids=OWNER_IDS,
            intents=Intents.all(),
        )

    def run(self, version):
        self.VERSION = version

        with open("./lib/bot/token.0", "r", encoding="utf-8") as tf:
            self.TOKEN = tf.read()

        print("Running bot...")
        super().run(self.TOKEN, reconnect=True)

    async def on_connect(self):
        print("Bot Connected")

    async def on_disconnect(self):
        print("Bot Disconnected")

    async def on_error(self, err, *args, **kwargs):
        if err == "on_command_error":
            await args[0].send("Something went wrong.")
            
        await self.stdout.send("An error occured.")
        raise

    async def on_command_error(self, ctx, exc):
        if isinstance(exc, CommandNotFound):
            pass
    
        elif hasattr(exc, "original"):
            raise exc.original
        
        else:
            raise exc

    async def on_ready(self):
        if not self.ready:
            
            self.ready = True
            self.guild = self.get_guild(GUILD_ID)
            self.stdout = self.get_channel(854734087855013908)
            self.scheduler.start()

            await self.stdout.send("Now Online!")

        global result_main

        choices = ["yes", "no"]

        run = True
        while run:
            channel = bot.get_channel(854734087855013908)
            if channel == channel:
            
                msg = await bot.wait_for("message", )
                ygo_card = msg.content[1:]
                message = ygo_card
                value_random = random.choice(choices)

                embed = Embed(title="Card Name:", description=message)
                embed.add_field(name="Available: ", value=value_random, inline=False)
                await channel.send(embed=embed)
            
            print("Bot Ready")

        else:
            print("Bot Reconnected")

    async def on_message(self, message):
        pass



bot = Bot()
```

Answer (score 0):

If channel == channel is always true, you probably meant something like self.channel